# CSS !important declaration not working in Outlook 2007

Tags: html, css, outlook, outlook-2007

I want to create an email template with anchor color red, it should be with **!important** declaration to avoid inheriting other style values.

Unfortunately it is not render properly in Outlook 2007/2010... Any one have similar experience? Issue related to !important tag support in Outlook.

I have listed my code here, Please have look.

```
<body><table width="500" border="1" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text into <a href="#">electronic</a> typesetting, and more recently with <a href="#" style="color:#F30408 !important;">desktop</a> publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58228507/3771354

Answer (score 3):

I have tried the following code:

```
<p><a href='#' style='color: #F30408'>desktop</a></p>
<p><a href='#' style='color: #F30408 !important'>desktop</a></p>
<p><a href='#'><font color='#F30408'>desktop</a></p>
```

You can see the results here:

[image]

So basically, <kbd>!important</kbd> doesn't work in Outlook 2010 it seems.

Answer (score 3):

I tried this and it worked for me in Outlook 2007. Outlook sometime failed to execute the css inside style even if we give !important. So try to use this way, it will work in Outlook and gmail also.

```html
<table width="500" border="1" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text into <a href="#">electronic</a> typesetting, and more recently with <a href="#"><font color="#F30408">desktop</font></a> publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```