# jQuery: Get inner HTML from a HTML code within a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have a variable which contains a html element:

```
alert(aData[3]);
```

gives me:

```
BLA BLA BLA
<div style="display: none">
 <table>....</table>
</div>
```

I'm trying to figure out how to get the contents WITHIN the div-tag from the variable `aData[3]` via jQuery. I tried various things:

```
elem = $(aData[3]).find("div");
alert(elem.html());

// OR
elem = $(aData[3]).find("div");
alert(elem[0].html());

// OR
elem = $(aData[3]).find("div");
alert($(elem[0]).html());

// OR
elem = $(aData[3], 'div');
alert(elem.html());
```

Can't get any of those to work. How to the correct version? :(
Thanks a lot

Comment: shouldn't you end `display: none` with a `;`?

Comment: @DejaVu There are no styles to follow so it doesn't matter.

Comment: I didn't understand what you wanted to say @Deja Vu, but nevermind, as oGeez clarified, it probably won't matter anyway

Comment: @oGeez Alright, but it looks cleaner for me if it ends with a `;`. It was just a suggestion

Comment: Can you put jsfiddle?

Comment: What to end with `;`?

Comment: @tim He means, quite rightly, that styles should be separated by a semi-colon. Although the last property in the block doesn't need one. More [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939595/leaving-out-the-last-semicolon-of-a-css-block)

Comment: @tim — He is suggesting that you use `;` as a rule terminator in your CSS instead of as a rule separator. It has no bearing on your actual problem.

Comment: Ah I see, sure I know that, but for one property, it's not necessary, is it? And yes, actually no relation to my problem in any way...

Comment: @tim That's right, the issue is irrelevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`find` looks for *descendants* of elements in the jQuery object, but `div` is the highest level element in your HTML (it isn't a descendant of anything).

Just don't use `find`.

```
elem = $(aData[3]);
alert(elem.html());
```

Comment: Thanks, thats very short, clean and nice

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap your string with another dom object to use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/).

```
elem = $('<div />',{
  html: aData[3];
}).find("div");
alert(elem);
```

Comment: And then `elem.html()` or what?

Comment: you would do .html() if you want elem's html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [parseHTML](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) to convert the string into an array of DOM elements.

Comment: Thanks, but overhead in this case :)