# Github repository; I want to know how to color my text for my website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a website for a project and i've tried doing h1 { color: rgb(222, 222, 222,); } and it hasn't changed or anything

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    h1 {
      color: rgb(222, 222, 222)
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1> Welcome </h1>
</body>
```

Comment: Please share a minimal amount of code thus we can check what's wrong with your code.

Comment: What has the question to do with Github?

Answer (score 1):

The code supplied works as expected in a code snippet (the h1 text color is gray).

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    h1 {
      color: rgb(222, 222, 222)
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1> Welcome </h1>
</body>
```

There is a missing semicolon on the CSS rule. Although this is optional on the last style in a CSS rule, it's good practice to use semicolons:

```
color: rgb(222, 222, 222);
```

Comment: It's not a good practice though but it will work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939595/leaving-out-the-last-semicolon-of-a-css-block

Comment: I tried that and put it into my index.html but it doesn't change my website at all and i put it into my readme.md and it show <style> [random stuff insert here]</style> edit: im using github by the way so i don't know if that changes anything

Comment: @Icy Readme.md files use markdown format, not HTML.

Comment: @Icy What? That is not how github works. HTML does not influence the README. Put it into your readme.md and you should get raw HTML because Markdown is a different language than HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Clear cache in your browser, something code was cached

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you don't understand Github and are just learning. Your code works, but if you put it in the `index.html`, it doesn't have any effect on the README. And if you put it in `README.md`, it doesn't render because it uses Markdown and the HTML file uses a HTML interpreter. All of this is from the comments of another answer.

Comment: The question doesn't mention a README.

Comment: @Sean You don't understand. This is all from the comment of another answer.

Answer (score -2):

I think you might have forgot semi colons at the end of your code:

```
h1 { color: rgb(222, 222, 222) }
```

to

```
h1 { color: rgb(222, 222, 222); }
```

Comment: In that case Semikolon is not essentielly needed

Comment: You don't need semicolons because there is only one line of CSS.