# How to conditionally render css with clsx?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, classname, conditional-rendering

I have a button component that's supposed to change colors based on  its status (passed in by props). The colors are stored in a css file.  I read that the clsx npm is a good one to use, but I don't quite understand its [documentation](https://openbase.io/js/clsx/documentation). How do I use clsx to conditionally render my button?

```
  import  colors from './colors.css'

  <MyButton
        className={cx( )} //<------ ???
      />
```

and my colors.css file:

```
.accept {
  background-color: green
}

.reject {
  background-color: red
}

.warning {
  background-color: orange
}
```

Comment: Try not to miss out the semicolons: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939595/leaving-out-the-last-semicolon-of-a-css-block

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
<MyButton className={clsx({ 'your-class-name': yourConditional })} />
```

If your class is a variable, you can add inside `[]`.

```
<MyButton className={clsx({ [yourClassName]: yourConditional })} />
```